# Magento: Blank Template Mail with Observer

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created an observer to send mail after the invoice is made. The mail is delivered but it is blank. Can you help me to understand why pls?

```
<?php
class Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model_Observer
{
public function notifyOwnerEvent($observer)
{

    // parameters you can get from the $observer parameter:
    // array(’payment’ ? $this, ‘invoice’ ? $invoice)

    $payment = $observer->getPayment();
    $invoice = $observer->getInvoice();

    // derivative data
    $order = $invoice->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order

    $ownerEmail = 'test@gmail.com';

    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->loadDefault('order_copy_for_supplier');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Prova di Ordine Confermato dopo pagamento');

    // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
    $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');


   //Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    //Getting the Store General E-Mail.
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

    $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
    $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);   


    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
    ->setToName($senderName)
    ->setToEmail($ownerEmail)
    ->setBody($processedTemplate)
    ->setSubject('Oggetto :')
     ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
     ->setFromName($senderName)
     ->setType('html');
     try{
     //Confimation E-Mail Send
     $mail->send();
     }
     catch(Exception $error)
     {
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
     return false;
     }


    return $this;  // always return $this.
}

}
```

the config.xml file is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <notifyowner>
            <class>Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model</class>
        </notifyowner>
    </models>          
    <events>
            <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                    <notifyOwnerEvent>
                            <class>notifyowner/observer</class>
                            <method>notifyOwnerEvent</method>
                    </notifyOwnerEvent>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_pay >     
    </events>
    <template>
        <email>
            <order_copy_for_supplier module="Electricjesus_Notifyowner">
                <label>Nuovo Ordine Per Fornitore</label>
                <file>order_copy_for_supplier.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </order_copy_for_supplier>
        </email>
    </template>
 </global>
```

And Then the Electricjesus_Notifyowner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Electricjesus_Notifyowner>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Electricjesus_Notifyowner >
</modules>
```

and the template:

```
<!--@subject {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Nuovo Ordine Per Fornitore # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()":"Customer Name",
"var store.getFrontendName()":"Store Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')":"Billing Address",
"var payment_html":"Payment Details",
"var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order":"Order Items  Grid",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note"}
@-->
<!--@styles
@-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="email-heading">
                    <h1>Nuovo ordine da produrre{{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
                    <p>Gentile Fornitore, vi preghiamo di mettere in produzione il seguente ordine. Abbiamo già effettuato bonifico per la corrispondente somma a voi dovuta secondo la scontistica del 60+10 sul vostro listino. Vi preghiamo, effettuata la spedizione di inviarci il codice di tracking. Grazie.</p>
                </td>
                <td class="store-info">
                    <h4>Info da inviare a </h4>
                    <p>
                        {{depend store_phone}}
                        <b>Chiamaci:</b>
                        <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a><br>
                        {{/depend}}
                        {{depend store_hours}}
                        <span class="no-link">{{var store_hours}}</span><br>
                        {{/depend}}
                        {{depend store_email}}
                        <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                        {{/depend}}
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="order-details">
        <h3>Ns. Ordine N. <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
        <p>Effettuato il {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="order-information">
    <td>
        {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
            <tr>
                <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {{/if}}
        {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="address-details">
                    <h6>Fattura a:</h6>
                    <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                </td>
                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                <td class="address-details">
                    <h6>Spedizione a:</h6>
                    <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                </td>
                {{/depend}}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                <td class="method-info">
                    <h6>Metodo di spedizione:</h6>
                    <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                </td>
                {{/depend}}
                <td class="method-info">
                    <h6>Metodo di pagamento:</h6>
                    {{var payment_html}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Can you help me to undestand why my mail are white? Only subject is visible. Thank you!

-EDIT-
I've updated the observer code and added template html

Comment: you may have a php error. can you check the logs? also you can try printing out $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables) to preview the output.

Comment: I checked var/log system and exception but nothing is stored inside. How I need to do to see the preview? I'm not really good in php..

Comment: I've edited the code in the post

Comment: Can you help me ?